# MVC Core popup modal parameters

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a scenario where i should create number of buttons based on no. of items on DB.

and when a button is clicked, a popup modal should appear with a submit button.

when i submit, the parameters that is selected is not passed to my post controller Activate(Code code)

Can anyone help ?

I have this model:

```
public class Code
{
     public int CodeId { get; set; }
     public string CodeName { get; set; }
     public string CodeColor { get; set; }
     public int PagerNo { get; set; }
}
```

and This is my controller:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_code.Entity.GetAll());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Activate(Code code)
        {
            int codeId = code.CodeId;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CoreLibrary.Entities.Code>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#item-@item.CodeId">
            @item.CodeName
        </button>

    }


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <form asp-action="Activate" asp-controller="Activation" method="post">

            <div class="modal fade" id="item-@item.CodeId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLongTitle">Are you sure?</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @item.CodeName will be activated !
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You should add hidden fields, you want to post, inside the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add hidden field which name is `CodeId` , that will bind to `Code` object during model binding :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <form asp-action="Activate" asp-controller="home" method="post">
        <input name="CodeId" type="hidden" value="@item.CodeId">  <-- pass CodeId
        <div class="modal fade" id="item-@item.CodeId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLongTitle">Are you sure?</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @item.CodeName will be activated !
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below: I have added hidden fields

```html
@model IEnumerable<CoreLibrary.Entities.Code>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#item-@item.CodeId">
            @item.CodeName
        </button>

    }


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <form asp-action="Activate" asp-controller="Activation" method="post">

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.CodeId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CodeName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CodeColor)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PagerNo)
            <div class="modal fade" id="item-@item.CodeId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLongTitle">Are you sure?</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @item.CodeName will be activated !
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggested answer, but it is not working.

Comment: Still my controller is receiving null